# How to remove HorizontalScrollBar in FlowLayoutPanel completely

Tags: c#, winforms, flowlayoutpanel

I have `FlowLayoutPanel` with multiple controls. Normally horizontal scroll bar is not visible and it is ok. But when I do resize horizontal scroll bar appears and blinks. After resize it is not visible again.

What I tried:

1)

```
int vertScrollWidth = SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth;
flowlayoutPanel.Padding = new Padding(0, 0, vertScrollWidth, 0);
```

That does not work completely.

2)

```
flowlayoutPanel.AutoScroll = false;
flowlayoutPanel.HorizontalScroll.Enabled = false;
flowlayoutPanel.HorizontalScroll.Visible = false;
flowlayoutPanel.AutoScroll = true;
```

After that horizontal scroll bar is disabled, but still visible.

3)

```
flowlayoutPanel.AutoScroll = true;
flowlayoutPanel.WrapContents = false;
```

That does not work completely.

4)

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool ShowScrollBar(IntPtr hWnd, int wBar, bool bShow);

protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e) {
    ShowScrollBar(this.flowlayoutPanel.Handle, SB_HORZ, false);
    base.OnShown(e);
}
```

That does not work completely.

5)

```
flowlayoutPanel.SuspendLayout();
//resize controls inside flowlayoutPanel
flowlayoutPanel.ResumeLayout();
```

Much better, horizontal scroll bar blinks less, but still blinks

6)

```
//ResizeBegin event
flowlayoutPanel.AutoScroll = false;
//ResizeEnd event
flowlayoutPanel.AutoScroll = true;
```

That does not work completely.

Comment: Explain 'does not work completely'..

Comment: 'does not work completely' = after adding these lines nothing changed

Comment: What are you resizing? The form? It has three resize event..

Comment: Yes, I resize form with Resize event. Form contains splitcontainer. SplitContainer has flowlayoutpanel inside.

Comment: There is no universal solution to this problem.  The big problem with scrollbars is that they take space, reducing the available size to layout controls.  That gives the layout engine *two* possible solutions, if the panel is close to full then it could fit with the vertical scrollbar *or* the horizontal one.  You see it flickering back and forth between the two solutions, it doesn't favor one over the other.  Only way to get ahead is to use SuspendLayout() better or size the FLP so it is either always too big or too small.

Comment: I tried SuspendLayout in different variations, for example Suspend in ResizeBegin event and Resume on ResizeEnd event, still no success.

Answer (score 1):

I know it is an old post, but I found myself the solution for this problem.
(I did this for `VerticalScrollbar`, because this was my problem on a TopDown `FlowDirection` `FlowLayoutPanel`) but can be transcoded for `HorizontalScrollbar` as well.

```
// pContent is my FlowLayoutPanel, it has FlowDirection set to TopDown
// and WrapContent = true;
pContent.SuspendLayout();
// Populate the FlowLayoutPanel with controls
pContent.ResumeLayout();

// I want to show only HorizontalScrollbar
if (pContent.VerticalScroll.Visible)
    {
        pContent.AutoScroll = false;
        pContent.VerticalScroll.Visible = false;
        pContent.Height -= SystemInformation.HorizontalScrollBarHeight;
        pContent.AutoScroll = true;
        pContent.Height += SystemInformation.HorizontalScrollBarHeight;    
    }
```

So, for hiding HorizontalScrollbar:

```
// pContent has FlowDirection set to LeftRight and WrapContent = true;
pContent.SuspendLayout();
// Populate the FlowLayoutPanel with controls
pContent.ResumeLayout();

// I want to show only VerticalScrollbar
if (pContent.HorizontalScroll.Visible)
    {
        pContent.AutoScroll = false;
        pContent.HorizontalScroll.Visible = false;
        pContent.Width -= SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth;
        pContent.AutoScroll = true;
        pContent.Width += SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth;    
    }
```